# Datausingencoding that doesn't replace plus signs

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking for a datausingencoding parameter that doesn't swallow up plus signs. I was using NSASCIIENCODING but since I'm trying to send a uiimage to the server and the base64 string had plus signs in them, it seems like that form of encoding takes out the plus sign sending a modified encoded string to the server thereby not allowing the image to be decoded server side. I'm looking for something that won't alter the base64 string.

Comment: If you are having trouble with some code, post the relevant code so people can help you determine the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, here is the solution I found on stackoverflow

> thanks, now I figured it out. It seems I needed to run my string through the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: first, then I needed to run it through replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B" and several more of those replaces for different characters, because stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: doesn't escape them all

Comment: You can also use the lower-level Core Foundation function `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()` which allows you to specify characters to not escape (though of course then you have to deal with CF's create rule).

Comment: If you were going to percent-escape, then `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` is the way to go. But you might consider posting your request in a different manner so that you don't have to do that at all. Or, better, so you don't have to Base64 encode at all (which makes the request 33% larger). If you want to solve the broader problem, you should update your question with particulars about the nature of the request, code you're using to create the request, your flexibility in tweaking the server code, etc.